# Virtual Machine Monitoring KQL yielding empty results

Tags: azure, monitoring

I have enabled Azure Monitoring in one of our virtual machine. Is been 4 days the virtual machine is on, below is the query:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "Memory" and
(CounterName == "Available MBytes Memory" or // the name used in Linux records
CounterName == "Available MBytes") // the name used in Windows records
|  summarize avg(CounterValue) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15min), Computer, _ResourceId // bin is used to set the time grain to 15 minutes
| render timechart
```

The output of Perf itself is empty. The same thing goes for `Update`, it show me zero results.

These are the two extensions I have installed on the VM

[image]

Also I have created the Data collection rule to send below data to the log analytics

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added Azure Monitor logs to the Performance counters and now it is showing the Perf data